# Are there any dicylic graphing programs for chess?

Tags: software, programming, computer-chess

Although chess is frequently thought of as a tree structure, it is not because positions can be arrived at through different move orders and moves can be repeated.  Are their graphing programs/databases representing chess moves that can be used to illustrate this?

Comment: What exactly are you thinking of? For what purpose do you want this? Something like: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-cNVCvQNxkkQ/UNZONkCry7I/AAAAAAAAAZs/p21dAAXLXGE/s1600/sicilian.png or https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4017/4391267493_ab44e3f827_b.jpg ?

Comment: That seems like an example of a tree structure.

Comment: The first is not a tree. But anyway is that something like you want or something completely different?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, but these are simple chess engines with didactic intentions in mind https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Sunfish https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Pulse

Comment: Something that is recursive and that could be placed into a database.  Not simply graphed out..